# Live Audio Network Feed via LAN

Tags: c#, network-programming, naudio, loopback, networkstream

This particular problem is that when attempting to send Loopback audio from one PC to another, the audio buffers and stalls for fractions of a second; micro stutters occur.

Using the example from [NAudio's ReadFullyStream](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudioDemo/Mp3StreamingDemo/ReadFullyStream.cs) sends the audio with no hitches, only that upon processing, it will pause for the length of a second or two.

Server:

```cs
private void Capture_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    stream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```

and client:

```cs
wave = new WaveOut()
{
    DesiredLatency = 500
};
wave.Init(buff); //BufferedWaveProvider
wave.Play();
while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    buff.AddSamples(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

The code I am using is painfully simplified, and is using Tcp since I put it together before I knew Udp was the preferred choice.

The current result is that audio plays, but stutters every half-second or so.

Comment: So, have you tried to play the raw audio data outside of your TCP implimentation ?

Comment: I have. While running two instances of the program on the same machine, I can hear the audio being played back, only that it is the loopback feed that is being heard so it stacks and gets kind of dirty after a few seconds. I will record the audio to a file to satisfy your question, and listen back to check.

Comment: So upon local recording of the loopback audio by using the same Client method used to read the NetworkStream, the recording was clear and had no distortions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A network using `UdpClient` solved the microstuttering, although it did not resolve stuttering altogether. This might be accomplished by sending audio as encoded Mp3 and decoding it client-side. As it stands, it is sending uncompressed data live with minor gaps.